# Best of two ways to select rows in a Pandas DataFrame based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a Pandas DataFrame and I want to extract certain rows based on a condition. An example will make it clearer:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(12, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
df1 = df.drop(df[df["A"] % 2 == 0].index)
df2 = df[~(df["A"] % 2 == 0)]
```

The DataFrames df1 and df2 are the same. Are there cases where one method is preferable over the other (memory usage, speed, readibility...) ?

(I wrote `~(condition)` in the second method, but there are obviously cases where either a condition or its negation is more naturally expressed.)